# Is there a way to switch between discrete and integrated video cards via keyboard shortcut?

Tags: mac, gpu, video-adapter

Is there a way to switch between discrete and integrated video cards via keyboard shortcut in MacOS?

Comment: Did you try https://gfx.io ? it doesn't have a feature to change video card via keyboard, but it has menu bar status item in top right corner.

Comment: Thanks. I do have that but I need a keyboard shortcut ability. I am troubleshooting a gpu crash that blacks out the screen but not the computer and I need to be able to switch to the other gpu without the mouse. I tried using the MacOS Keyboard Shortcuts in preferences to try to access gfx.io's menu items but they don't seem to work (I think because it's a menu bar app not a regular app?).

Comment: Perhaps a bit off-topic, but is your mac eligible for this repair program: https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/

Comment: Nope, it doesn't seem to be one of the known cases and the hardware tests they ran in the store don't show anything. I know it doesn't crash the whole computer because audio will keep playing. If I could just switch to the functioning gpu via keyboard shortcut I could investigate further but right now there is no way.